# jsp include not working

Tags: java, html, jsp

i am trying to learn jsp, and when i include another .jsp file to my main page, its contents are not shown. here is the code

main.jsp

```
<html>
<head><title>the include action</title></head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>the include</h2>
<jsp:include page="/date.jsp"/ >
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

date.jsp

```
<p>
  Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>
</p>
```

Comment: you add that jsp tag at the top. First try that. Also, have you configured your jsp config in your web.xml?

Comment: Actually first tell us what error message you are receiving?

Comment: no i have not how to do that?

Comment: i am not receiving any error but just a blank screen with data from main,jsp

Comment: <%@ include file="/path/to/some/file.jsp" %> is what you nee.d try that

Comment: this is how you setup jsp config inside web.xml: <jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

Answer (score 7):

include like this

```
<jsp:include page="date.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

or use this at top of your jsp

```
<%@ include file="date.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using import statement,If your current page and `date.jsp` are in same folder.

```
<c:import url="date.jsp" >
```

instead of

```
<jsp:include page="/date.jsp"/ >
```

N.B: Before using c taglib, import it first and include `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` to your classpath.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try it with the page directive:

<%@ include file="date.jsp"%> --> .jspf is "standard" for including jsp files.

And try to leave out the slash at the beginning. Is there also any error message which appears?

br
Stefan

Comment: what is ".jspf is "standard" for including jsp files." Also please add four spaces before <%@ ....

Comment: I read in a book, that jspf is the file extension for the jsp sites, which will be included. So you see on a first view that this page is included from another. The spaces are in, but I have copied it out from my ide.